# Windows 11 freezes after resizing a window, re-drawing many things at once, etc

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, freeze, hardware-failure, windows-11

UPDATE: Problem **didn't seem to appear again** after updating to Windows 22H2 b22621.963, Nvidia GTX 1660 driver v528.02, and also **disabling hardware-accelerated GPU scheduling** (See probably related [issue](https://github.com/moonlight-stream/nvidia-gamestream-issues/issues/27) here).

---

*(Windows 11: v21H2 b22000.434 | Nvidia GTX 1660 driver: v511.65 [latest])*

After upgrading to Windows 11, these cause the screen to freeze:

1. Turning off the monitor and turning on again
2. Resizing a window
3. Adjusting screen resolution
4. Re-drawing many things at once [e.g. watching videos
   full screen, minimizing windows, etc.] *(probably related to 2 and 3)*

The system doesn't stop responding when the screen freezes ~70% of the time, as I can still SSH into WSL *(screen remains the last moment when it froze)* and be back to normal by turning the monitor off/on; however, the rest of the time when the display freezes, the system also stops responding *(`CapsLock` doesn't work, turning monitor off/on displays a black screen)*, with the only way to recover being to hard reset the system.

None of these fix the issue:

- Reinstalling graphics driver by DDUing it

  - A post in the Nvidia forum talking about the same kind of problem after signing in with Windows 10 with driver v471.xx, but it didn't provide any effective solutions and why it would happen still remains unknown
- Running system checks [`dism` and `sfc`]

Any ideas why this happens and how to deal with it?

---

The Reliability Monitor's report contains four different errors:

1. 2021/10/5 22:57

   ```cmd
   LiveKernelEvent, 0x193, Parameters: 0x815, 0x2, 0xffffb1869ddd2080, 0x0
   ID: LKD_0x193_DxgkrnlLiveDump:815__watchdog!WdpDbgCaptureKernelDump
   ```
2. 2021/10/22 21:08

   ```cmd
   LiveKernelEvent, 0x124, Parameters: 0x7, 0xffffad8ad9a46020, 0x0, 0x0
   ID: LKD_0x124_7_GenuineIntel_FIRMWARE_0x100300100000000_IMAGE_GenuineIntel.sys
   ```
3. Shortly after #2:

   ```cmd
   LiveKernelEvent, 0x193, Parameters: 0x185, 0x2, 0xffffa98a822c9080, 0x0
   ID: LKD_0x193_DxgkrnlLiveDump:815__watchdog!WdpDbgCaptureTriageDump
   ```
4. 2022/2/5 3:47

   ```cmd
   LiveKernelEvent, 0x1cc, Parameters: 0xffff8008ef73a110, 0xffff8008f4882080, 0xeec5a2, 0x96
   ID: LKD_0x1cc_EXRESOURCE_TIMEOUT_OWNERTHREAD_nt!ExpResourceTimeoutCaptureLiveDump
   ```

   - This happened this morning, crashing lots of programs, all with error messages related to memory exhaustion

---

EDIT1: Another interesting thing when I profiled my system when the screen froze. It seems that when the screen freezes (the highlighted part), `DWM-Core` and `DxgKrnl` performs entirely differently. I suppose they both stopped working, but I don't know whether it is related to this problem.
[Profile Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzOW4.png)

Comment: Get the PC manufacturer's Driver Update App, run it and update all drivers:  BIOS, Video and Chipset (if one) for sure.

Comment: `Dx` is DirectX, this is definitely a driver issue. But, given you have the latest driver version, there shouldn't be a compatibility issue. It might be worth reaching out to nVidia support.

Comment: When you installed the driver, did you use the driver from Nvidia's site or from Windows Update? Do you ever get BSODs? Have you fully installed the GTX display drivers via Device Management, ticking the box to delete the installation/source files?

Comment: I downloaded the driver from Nvidia's website. There's no BSODs at all, although I could manually generate one, since I enabled CrashOnCtrlScroll. There's one BSOD from the logitech camera driver, but I think it has nothing to do with this problem. I DDUed the old driver before installing a new one, so I wouldn't consider that as a problem.

Comment: was the computer legitimate to upgrade or did you done an invalid one?

Comment: It is legitimately upgraded using Windows 11 upgrade assistant. No problems or driver imcompatibilities were being found when upgrading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem **didn't seem to appear again** after updating to Windows 22H2 b22621.963, Nvidia GTX 1660 driver v528.02, and also **disabling hardware-accelerated GPU scheduling** (See probably related [issue](https://github.com/moonlight-stream/nvidia-gamestream-issues/issues/27) here).

Issue mentioned above matched the symptoms of my problem, so I suppose it was the same problem I'm facing.

It seems like Nvidia is having some problems with its driver, and it still hasn't been resolved yet. By now, the workaround is to disable hardware-accelerated GPU scheduling.